# UIView SubClass And IBAction Of its Sub Views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, actionlistener

I Have Created a SubClass Of UIView using xib and swift , This view has a UIButton as a subview in xib file and a actionlistener in Swift File . This View is being allocated by some other class and used as a subview further . The view is loaded on UI Correctly but the action actionlistener of the button is not being called and , even some of the buttons are not even clickable .

```
import UIKit


class SampleSubView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonR: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        self.commonInit();

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame);
        self.commonInit();

    }
    func commonInit() {

        let view =  NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SampleSubView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView;
        self.addSubview(view);

    }

    func setOptionText(textStr:String){

        self.buttonRef.setTitle(textStr, forState: UIControlState.Normal);


    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("hi");
    }


}
```

Comment: I think This problem is  occurring  when the view is allocated with   init(frame: CGRect) , If i give class of any view in the story board as SampleSubView  then   init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) is called and it is working fine .

Answer (score 1):

// i think view is added on top of the button from commonInit method, so events didnt fire on that button once check

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an action outlet connected from the storyboard to your swift file, or add the following to `commonInit()`:

```
func commonInit() {
  buttonR.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SampleSubView.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
```

Comment: The same is working fine if i load the view Statically

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it fixed, below are the changes i made

- I made it as sub class "UIControl" instead of "UIView"
- I changed func commonInit() as below

  ```
  func commonInit(){
                      view = loadViewFromNib();
                      view.frame = bounds;
                      view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth,.FlexibleHeight];
                      addSubview(view);
  }
  ```

  func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView{

  ```
          let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType);
          let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle);
          let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIControl;
          return view;

      }
  ```